# Where does the (2D) Hilbert curve map a given point to?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

If the Hilbert curve maps the interval [0,1] onto the unit square, is there a formula that tells us where a given point $x \in [0,1]$ will be taken?

EDIT: For example, it seems intuitive that $0$ is mapped to $(0,0)$, $1$ is mapped to $(0,1)$, and $\frac{1}{2}$ is mapped to $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$, ...

Comment: [Hilbert curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_curve)?

Comment: That's the one!

Comment: Yes, there is a formula. You can find it in my answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/921985).